# Subtracting PDF form fields using PDF JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

So what I have written works until one EA1 is 0. When EA1 is 0 the field that displays the difference is blank.  This is also the case if BA1 and EA1 are 0 the field that displays the difference is blank. So what i would like it to show for example would be 44-0=44. Thank you

This code also has to display 0 when the two values are the same. for example 55-55=0. it currently does this but i am not sure if thats part of my problem.

```
var TotValA = getField("BA1").value;
var CostBasA = getField("EA1").value;

if (CostBasA == ("")) {
    this.getField("B1").value = ("");
}
else {
    this.getField("B1").value = (TotValA - CostBasA);
}
```

Comment: The very first question is, under which condition is the result "legal" (this essentially means blank fields). The second question is, if it is "legal", are there any further rules (what happens with input 0, for example). Now, for the actual piece of code, in which field and which event is this code attached?

Comment: This piece of code is attached a field that displays the result of this code. it attached as a "custom calculation script"

Comment: The calculation result for the field the calculation script is attached, is not field.value, but event.value. So, in your example, it would be "event.value = "" ; " instead of "this.getField("B1").value = "" ; " … and so on.

Comment: third field being "B1"

Comment: my issue is that if "EA1" is 0 then "BA1" is empty, for example 9-0 = (blank field).

Comment: I changed them to event.value and the issue was still present.

Comment: So, what should BA1 be when EA1 is 0? However, from the code I don't see any way that BA1 is affected by the calculation. Could it be that there is some rogue code floating around in your form which resets BA1?

Comment: B1 needs to display the calculation of "BA1" and "EA1. parameters are:

BA1 - EA1 = B1, if either BA1, or EA1 are 0 then it needs to account for that, currently it leaves B1 blank. second parameter is if either BA1 or EA1 are blank then it needs to assume there is a 0 and  run the calculation